# Parse US number format in German Excel

Tags: vba, excel, localization, numbers

I am creating an Excel file that helps people to automatically process data. Within this sheet, there are numbers that have to be parsed (and converted to other units, etc. Simple calculations).

The **numbers come in US format** which means they look like:

```
0,000,000.00
```

**In Germany**, numbers are displayed like this:

```
0.000.000,00
```

In VBA, I actually don't know, which **localized Version of Excel** is in use (German or English).

**Question:**
Is there an easy way to **parse the US format numbers into data type Double** regardless of the Excel localization, that is used by the user?

Comment: It isn't quite clear - to me at least - what you need here. So you are parsing text in VBA?

Comment: @brettdj I'd assume that he's parsing it in VBA because he has to parse "mass data" within SQL.

Comment: The file is also used by other people. Those people may use Englisch Excel. There is a letter behind each number, that I have to seperate using VBA. After doing that (1) Englisch Excel treats the remaining number as number. (2) German Excel treats the remaining number as text. If cannot replace the decimal signs, because I don't know, which version is in used by the user.

Comment: could you post this specific part of your code?

Comment: It's a simple replacement. (1) Remove commas. (2) Replace dots with commas. For the German version, this works. But not in the Englisch version, because there, Excel is aware that it is dealing with a number.

Comment: That could be an interim version. Because I would have to remove the decimals. But I will try this. Thank you.

Comment: It works, but that is not a satisfying solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some notes. I did not change locale to test.

```
'http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb177675(v=office.12).aspx
Debug.Print Application.International(xlCountryCode) 'Excel locale
Debug.Print Application.International(xlCountrySetting) 'Windows locale
sDecimal = Application.International(xlDecimalSeparator)
sThousand = Application.International(xlThousandsSeparator)

sNumber = "1,000,000.00"

If sThousand <> "," Then
    If sDecimal <> "." Then
        sNumber = Replace(sNumber, ",", "")
        sNumber = Replace(sNumber, ".", sDecimal)
    End If
End If

Debug.Print sNumber
```

Comment: Thank you. This fits to my needs!

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution may be:
`cells(y, x) = Val(Replace(cells(y, x).Text, ",", ""))`

Val always uses the . as decimal mark (CDbl for example uses cultural settings, tested in a German Excel).